# Is it possible to search for and view a public Facebook page without a Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

There is a small charity that I'm interested in that has a public Facebook page.  I don't know the exact URL of that page.  The charity does not have a website, telephone number, or active email address.

I've tried using search engines to find their Facebook page, but have not come up with any valid results.

***Without a Facebook account***, is it possible to find and view that public Facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would Google the name and add 'facebook' in the end.

So my search would be 'name of charity facebook'

Now if you don't find it in the search results, try to google something general like 'george facebook' and click on the google result that gets to all the profiles with that name. In this case it is  facebook.com/public/George-George . In that page there is a facebook search bar and you can search using that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, there is no search bar within Facebook when you are not logged in.

Comment: Of course there is!! I googled 'george facebook' and got this page https://www.facebook.com/public/George-George there is a search bar in the upper left!

Comment: Interesting!  When it finds a single result, there is no search bar.  But when the results are ambiguous, there is one.  Thanks!

Comment: I will update my answer with that

Answer (score 1):

You can, but keep in mind that the information you'll get will be pretty minimal.

Two options I know:

1. Search Google for `site:facebook.com some user`. It will search `some user` under the mentioned site - facebook.
2. Open your browser and in the address bar enter `https://www.facebook.com/public/someone-anonymous` to search for people with the name `someone anonymous`. The keynote here is the `/public` path under the facebook domain.

   - Example: 
     This https://www.facebook.com/public/someone-anonymous would result:
     [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it possible to find and view the public Facebook page.

Use below link to search any page:

https://www.facebook.com/directory/pages/

There is an option to **Search for pages** on upper right of page. If you know the page name (or whatever name you have in your mind), just write it in search bar and click on Search, it will show all related results.

Keep in mind, if page has any age or country restriction, then it will ask for security test like given below:

[image]

You have to pass this security check to browse the page. Sometimes Facebook asks for this security test at search time itself. So no need to have the Facebook account, just pass the security test if required and see the public page or public profile of anyone.

---

Other link is : https://www.facebook.com/people-search.php

Search for any name, then sort it from left side options as per your requirement:

[image]

In your case click on **Pages** and it will show all the related pages.